# Is Double.MIN_VALUE is greater than zero in Java?

Tags: java, double

I found a bug in my code which boiled down to comparing `Double(0.0)` with `Double.MIN_VALUE`. Essentially, the following returns false:

```java
System.out.println(0.0 > Double.MIN_VALUE);
```

How is this possible?

Comment: For the .NET programmer: the equivalent for Java `Double.MIN_VALUE` in .NET is `double.Epsilon` . The .NET value of `double.MinValue` is the  *negative largest* (in absolute value) (finite) representable value.

Comment: Here is an ugly inconsistency in Java. `Integer.MIN_VALUE < 0` and `Double.MIN_VALUE > 0`.   There is no such inconsistency in .NET `int.MinValue < 0` and `double.MinValue < 0`

Answer (score 45, accepted):

According to the [javadoc for Double.MIN_VALUE](http://download.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/Double.html), MIN_VALUE is:

> A constant holding the smallest
>   positive nonzero value of type double

So Double.MIN_VALUE is not negative, it's the positive value that's as close as a Double can get to zero (without being zero).

Answer (score 6):

Double.MIN_VALUE is the smallest positive non-zero value which can be represented by a Java double (see the JavaDoc at http://download.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/Double.html).