# Why min value of Double is returned as 0.0

Tags: java

Why below program output is 0.0. It is to return the minimum value of Double.

```
public class Test {
    public static void main(String[] args){
        System.out.println(Math.min(Double.MIN_VALUE, 0.0d)); // 0.0
    }
}
```

The min value is close to zero but why it is giving 0.0 instead of exact value?

Comment: Possible duplicate: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5709073/is-double-min-value-is-greater-than-zero-in-java

Comment: Question is why it is printing 0.0 instead of closest value.Didnt getting that from existing question, thats why asked.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Refer to the JavaDoc for `Double.MIN_VALUE`

> A constant holding the smallest ***positive nonzero value of type double***,
>   2-1074. It is equal to the hexadecimal floating-point literal
>   0x0.0000000000001P-1022 and also equal to
>   Double.longBitsToDouble(0x1L).

`0.0d` is thus smaller than `Double.MIN_VALUE`