# Java: Compare Double 0 with Min/Max

Tags: java

I try to compare Doubles Min/Max with 0.0.

```
Double min = Double.MIN_VALUE;
Double max = Double.MAX_VALUE;

Double d = new Double (0.0);

System.out.println (min < d);
System.out.println (min.compareTo (d) < 0);

System.out.println (d < max);
System.out.println (d.compareTo (max) < 0);
```

I would expect all output to be true.

But instead I get

```
false
false
true
true
```

Why?

Comment: Of course, `Double.MIN_VALUE` is 0 so `min < d` would return false because `min = d` .

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Why is Double.MIN\_VALUE in not negative](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3884793/why-is-double-min-value-in-not-negative)

Comment: @preciousbetine No, `Double.MIN_VALUE` is not equal to 0.

Comment: @Jesper, well approximately it is with a little bit of rounding error..

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Is Double.MIN\_VALUE is greater than zero in Java?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5709073/is-double-min-value-is-greater-than-zero-in-java)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Look at the [documentation](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/Double.html#MIN_VALUE) of `Double.MIN_VALUE`, which says:

> A constant holding the smallest **positive** nonzero value of type double, 2<sup>-1074</sup>.

So this is a value larger than 0, which is why you 'false' if you check if it's smaller than zero.

Answer (score 1):

The issue is related to `IEEE-754`. In fact, `Double.MIN_VALUE` is equal to machine-epsilon which is the number represented by `0.00000...00`. The smallest double possible should be referred as

`-Double.MAX_VALUE`.